# Apache extracting .rar before serving content

Tags: apache-2.4, rar, data-extraction

I can't find any information online about this, hopefully someone here can help out.

Our website hosts MOV downloads, but server space has started to become a concern. We have found that RAR can reduce the file size by as much as 70%. Unfortunately if users download .rar items it would require that many of them install 3rd party extraction software, and we want to avoid that.

How might Apache extract a .rar file on the fly before sending the extracted contents to a user? (so users would download the MOV extracted file). If this type of inflation is feasible, are there any latency or CPU concerns I would need to consider? What Apache modules, or directives might work to accomplish this?

Comment: This is the exact opposite of `mod_deflate` which compresses the file before sending it over the network. If it reduces the file size with up to 70%, I would try to send it compressed over the network and then look into how the client can uncompress it. Perhaps look into a custom movie player?

Comment: nginx has an option `gzip_static` that can serve gzip compressed files directly to a user agent without having them uncompressed first. The user agent automatically uncompresses them upon receiving the data, if it supports gzip (and virtually all do). Of course, storage is cheap...

Answer (score 0):

Use 7Zip instead. It's free and it compresses better than rar.

For both 7zip and rar, you have to option to extract an archive via command line.

Example:

7za -oC:\ -y -pPassord x Archive.7z

(The above is the command line that extracts archive.7z to C:\ with the password 'Password')

Given such built-in functionality, which also exists in most archivers since MS-DOS era, I'm sure you just need to run this from apache and you'll have your file.

Of course, you will have to adapt the serving code a little, but that's something also relatively easy.